# Is there a way to remove businesses from LeafletJS

Tags: leaflet

Is there a way in Leaflet to remove things like businesses from a map and just leave other features? I can't see anything in the API.

Comment: I guess you are rather talking about the _tiles_. Leaflet just display those images. The tile server you choose is responsible for showing features on those tiles.

Answer (score 0):

Use mapbox, you can design you own tiles to use with leaflet